# Can $3q^2-1=m^2$ be not a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $3q^2-1=m^2$ is not a perfect square.
It is posing little confusion as the right hand side is already a perfect square

Comment: If the right hand is already a perfect square for all integer $m$ then surely it can never be true? I find this quite perplexing.

Comment: Ummmmmm, yeah. I'm thinking $m^2$ is a perfect square...

Comment: Maybe they want you to demonstrate that $m$ must not be an integer?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably intended to show that $3q^2-1$ cannot be a perfect square. To show this, note that $3n-1$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$ for any integer $n$, while a perfect square is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$.

Comment: So would that also imply that there are no integer solutions to $3q^2-1=m^2$? Or am I being stupid?

Comment: You are perfectly right. I used $n$ for the sake of greater generality, but in particular $3q^2-1$ cannot be a perfect square, the Diophantine equation $3q^2-1=m^2$ has no integer solutions.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, the equation does not even have rational solutions, but that takes more machinery.